# How To: Convert anonymous method to VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, anonymous-function, c#-to-vb.net

I have the following in C#:

```
public static void StartAnimation(UIElement animatableElement, DependencyProperty dependencyProperty, double toValue, double animationDurationSeconds, EventHandler completedEvent)
{
    double fromValue = (double)animatableElement.GetValue(dependencyProperty);

    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    animation.From = fromValue;
    animation.To = toValue;
    animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(animationDurationSeconds);

    //// HERE ----------------------------------------------------
    animation.Completed += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // When the animation has completed bake final value of the animation
        // into the property.
        //
        animatableElement.SetValue(dependencyProperty,
                                 animatableElement.GetValue(dependencyProperty));
        CancelAnimation(animatableElement, dependencyProperty);

        if (completedEvent != null)
        {
            completedEvent(sender, e);
        }
    };
```

I have some problems to convert the anonymous method to VB.NET.

My variant would be

```
  AddHandler animation.Completed,
    Function(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) As Boolean
      ' '
      ' When the animation has completed bake final value of the animation '
      ' into the property. '
      '
      animatableElement.SetValue(dependencyProperty, animatableElement.GetValue(dependencyProperty))
      CancelAnimation(animatableElement, dependencyProperty)

      completedEvent(sender, e)
      Return True
    End Function
```

I added `Function As Boolean` because without return type is not a function, but making a "Sub" I don't know how...

Some advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for anonymous methods is as follows:

```vb
AddHandler animation.Completed, _
    Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      ' '
      ' When the animation has completed bake final value of the animation '
      ' into the property. '
      '
      animatableElement.SetValue(dependencyProperty, animatableElement.GetValue(dependencyProperty))
      CancelAnimation(animatableElement, dependencyProperty)

      completedEvent(sender, e)
    End Sub
```

However, you need VB10 to be able to use this, previous versions don’t support this yet.

Comment: I tried but I think I had other errors that disoriented me. Thanks! )

Answer (score -1):

make it a SUB.

```
Public SUB <method name>(<parameters>)
'Body of the method
```